# how to print the minimum number of an array and its index calling them with a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I know to make this function i need to use void type here is my code..please someone show me how to make it with void type and call it in main i have tried to do it but i failed the latest thing i reach is to return the minimum number only of the array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int min(int arr[], int size)
{

    int small=arr[0];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        if(arr[i]<small)
            small=arr[i];
        return small;
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin>>size;
   int X[size];
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    cin>>X[i];

 cout<<"Min num in the array = " << min(X,size) <<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to use a reference for this if the function cannot return a value.

Comment: `auto ptr = std::min_element(X, X + size); std::cout << "min = " << *ptr << " index = " << std::distance(X, ptr);`

Comment: Note that in standard `c++` this is illegal: `int X[size];` because `size` must be a compile time constant,

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Return it in an argument that is passed by reference.

```
void min(int arr[], int& index)
{
   ...
}
```

and use the function as

```
int index = 0;
min(X, index);
cout << "The index of the min in the array = " << index << endl;
cout << "Min num in the array = " << X[index] << endl;
```

#### Option 2

Change the return type and return the index.

```
int min(int arr[])
{
   int index = 0;
   ...
   return index;
}
```

and use the function as

```
int index = min(X);
cout << "The index of the min in the array = " << index << endl;
cout << "Min num in the array = " << X[index] << endl;
```